# Best Practice for putting Appium Python UI test scripts in repository

Tags: android, python, git, android-studio, appium

I have some Appium testing scripts that needed to be put through a repository for version control, mainly Git.

I looked through Google to figure out what is the best way to go about this if you have an Android App project in Andriod Studio that you're writing the tests for (which happens to be in it's own Git repository), and so far I haven't found anything in my search.

My question is: Would it be better if I include the test scripts inside the Android studio project in it's Git repository, or would it be better if I put the test scripts in their own repository? If putting the scripts in the Android project is better, where in the project's file structure should I include the test scripts?

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I put my autotests in separate repository just to have them safe from deleting from my work computer or something else.
When I'm sure that my tests are stable I clone dev branch of the main project and making a pull request including my tests. When my request is merged we have a project repository with autotests.
Don't know any better ways, but for me it works great and very comfortable.